# How to verify if the disabled or stopped unix/linux service has a valid binary path?

Tags: linux, unix, service, binary

I would like to find out a given disabled or stopped unix/linux service, can we verify if it has a valid binary path?

I am not sure if it necessary to check out this? I am newbie to unix/linux world.
Or is it by default all installed unix/linux services are verified with the existence of its binary and path?

For example, the installed unix/linux service, sshd.
Check its status through the command "service sshd status"
Then, check its binary path using command "which sshd".

Is there a better way to check this out?

How if I would like to checkout all stopped/disabled unix/linux services that are either stopped or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Modern GNU/Linux-Distributions allow to manage software installations using a software management system. Different such systems are in use, but they all share a common principle: a package carries within itself a description of all of its dependencies, dependencies for installation, configuration and runtime. All of these dependencies are checked prior to an installation. So unlike one forces any actions here one has the guarantee that *if* a package is installed, then all its requirements are fulfilled.

Looking at your example of the sshd (the openssh daemon) this means: 
if you installed this package, then you can rely on the fact that all required components are installed and match in their versions and so on. IN this case the daemon control scripts and the main executable are actually contained inside the same package, this is typical for all daemon packages. So if that package is installed, then all of its content is installed.

You could manually check if all contained files of a package are actually existing. But if you really feel this has to be done, for example if you suspect some haves somehow were deleted by accident (which is actually pretty hard to do for such system files), then you can ask the software management system to verify the package integrities! For example on an openSUSE system you can say `zypper verify sshd`. That command verifies both: if all files mentioned in that package actually exist, are the ones originally installed (unaltered) and have correct permissions. In addition all package dependencies are checked as well. So if no error is thrown you can rely pretty much on the fact that everything is fine.

This is obviously jsut an example, different distributions use different management systems, as mentioned above. But they all offer more or less the same features. And once you understood the idea behind this approach you probably never want to miss that elegance and security any more...